Saturn Launch Vehicle (SLV) Designation Numbers
I'm struggling to find a full list of Saturn (Apollo) SLV designation numbers. The information from Google and various chatbots I've tried does not appear to be trustworthy.
My question is; does someone know an official source of this SLV information? Is is crucial for me,
because SA and AS numbering are random and also mixed with the 200 and 500 series. It's a big mess. Even NASA.gov contains cotrsadicting intormation.
I'm trying tocreate a excel with all Saturn-Apollo related launches, from Little Joe 1 to Skylab-4 and Soyuz-Apollo.
All sites that I encountered contain conflicting data. i.e.  Launch dates, different Boosters, CSM's or LM configurations etc. I have not seen one consistent file yet.

I could copy paste the chart on Wikipedia which I think answers your question, or at least it's a start, but copy/paste answers are not considered good answers, maybe someone will provide a more "value added" answer. As for Google and AI, those are brainless bots. Okay they have access to a lot more information than I do, but so does Wikipedia, which is maintained by a community (of humans), so it's a good place to begin information searches like this.

what further data are you asking for?  What do you want us to answer?

I'm not familiar with the use of the SLV prefix in relation to the Apollo launches. The boosters were SA-1xx for the Saturn I, SA-2xx for the Saturn IB, and SA-5xx for the Saturn V. Where did you originally encounter SLV numbers?

@StevePemberton the link you shared isn't correct, I think, if the Launch History Chart was what you meant to link to.

@ErinAnne - the link in my comment worked for me, it went straight to that section of the page. Maybe because it was in my cache, I tried it on a different device and it went elsewhere on the page. That's what I get for letting Google create the search, this is what it came up with; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#Assembly:~:text=%5B42%5D-,Launch%20history,-%5Bedit%5D whereas yours is simply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#Launch_history  You have to highlight my link in this comment to see what it was as it truncates on display

Hi,  you should add more details such as what we should specifically answer and what you are looking for. Giving such small questions does not provide us with enough intel.

Hi all, this my first time with aquestion, so please ... Now I need to find out how to respond first. Besides of that I suffer from brain damage and Englisch is not my native language. So if you like you can respond in Dutch, German, Swedish, Danish or Norwegian if that suits you better.

@ All...., Thank you for sharing your information ! The links are very helpfull

Every NASA document I've read refers to individual Saturns as "SA-xxx" and not SLV. Example from page 85 of the PDF.

I am sorry but my braindamage is preventing me tu use this site as I am supposed to. I thank you all for trying to help me out, but I need to leave. Bye.
